# outlook.com Delivery Failure to Custom Domains

Tags: email, hotmail, outlook.com

When I try to send an email from outlook.com, delivery fails. When I try to send the same email from Gmail, delivery succeeds. Here is the error message that I receive from outlook.com.

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822;user@someDomain.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.6.2
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;554 5.6.2 Delivery SMTP Error. Command: 3. Response: 535 5.0.0 Internal account error
. Type=1 (-798154547:817:-2147418113)
```

Why does this succeed in Gmail but fail in outlook.com? How can we fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Outlook Online"?

Comment: @thims By "Outlook Online" I mean [www.outlook.com](http://www.outlook.com) and/or [mail.live.com](http://mail.live.com).